# "new Trix is not defined" when using Basecamp / Trix Editor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, basecamp, trix

```
var attachment = new Trix.Attachment({ content: '<span class="mention">@trix</span>' })
element.editor.insertAttachment(attachment)
```

I used this snippet but it throwed error: Trix is not defined??
How can i handle it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because the script

```
var attachment = new Trix.Attachment({ content: '<span class="mention">@trix</span>' })
element.editor.insertAttachment(attachment)
```

is executing before the trix.js or the npm package(however you are implementing it). For now I haven't found a listener when Trix is ready so a quick solution is to use a CDN instead of those.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/trix/1.3.0/trix.js"></script>
```

These should work if you don't have a problem with the use of CDN